# Force Close because of onStop()

Tags: java, android

I finally got everything in my app done, but now whenever I exit it with anything except the Home button, it flashes a force close screen, and then it goes away. I know its not that big of a deal, but I really want that to stop happening, I finally got a logcat on it and it said there was no super.onStop(), so I added that, then it force closed again giving me a nullPointer,

I am closing the application by using moveTaskToBack(true), and any time I use it that is what it does, gives me a nullpointer in my onDraw method. I'm not sure what other info is needed, so let me know, thanks in advance for any help

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        if(checkState == -9){
            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bG, 0, 0, paint);
            canvas.drawBitmap(title, display.getWidth()/2 - title.getWidth()/2, 10, paint);
            canvas.drawBitmap(start, display.getWidth()/2 - start.getWidth()/2, 40 + title.getHeight(), paint);
            canvas.drawBitmap(instructions, display.getWidth()/2 - instructions.getWidth()/2, 80 + title.getHeight() + start.getHeight(), paint);
            canvas.drawBitmap(exit, display.getWidth()/2 - exit.getWidth()/2, 120 + title.getHeight() + start.getHeight() + exit.getHeight(), paint);
            canvas.drawBitmap(highScore, 0, display.getHeight() - highScore.getHeight(), paint);
            String high = highLevel + "";
            for(int i = 0; i < high.length(); i++){
                levelOnMenu = high.charAt(i) + "";
                levelPiece = Integer.parseInt(levelOnMenu);
                int placeX = highScore.getWidth() + levelNumber.getWidth()/2 ;
                if(high.length() == 1){

                }
                else if(high.length() == 2){
                    if(i == 0){

                    }
                    else{
                        placeX = placeX + levelNumber.getWidth();
                    }
                }
```

it is telling me that the first part of the onDraw is null, the drawColor...which doesn't make a lot of sense to me

Here is where I use moveTaskToBack()

```
if(checkState == -11){
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                if(x >= display.getWidth()/2 - pauseMenu.getWidth()/2 && x <= display.getWidth()/2 + pauseMenu.getWidth()/2 && y >=  display.getHeight()/2 - pauseMenu.getHeight()/2 && y <=  display.getHeight()/2 - pauseMenu.getHeight()/2 + pauseMenu.getHeight()/3){
                    checkState = previousState;
                }
                if(x >= display.getWidth()/2 - pauseMenu.getWidth()/2 && x <= display.getWidth()/2 + pauseMenu.getWidth()/2 && y >=  display.getHeight()/2 - pauseMenu.getHeight()/2 + pauseMenu.getHeight()/3 && y <=  display.getHeight()/2 - pauseMenu.getHeight()/2 + 2*(pauseMenu.getHeight()/3)){
                    if(sound){
                        sound = false;
                    }
                    else{
                        sound = true;
                    }
                }
                if(x >= display.getWidth()/2 - pauseMenu.getWidth()/2 && x <= display.getWidth()/2 + pauseMenu.getWidth()/2 && y >=  display.getHeight()/2 - pauseMenu.getHeight()/2 + 2*(pauseMenu.getHeight()/3) && y <=  display.getHeight()/2 - pauseMenu.getHeight()/2 + pauseMenu.getHeight()){

                    moveTaskToBack(true);
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you post any code that might indicate what is null that's triggering the NPE? Something in your onDraw?

Comment: Actually, it does do it when I hit home :/

Comment: And technically you shouldn't need to call moveTaskToBack(true), since onPause(), which is called before onStop(), means your activity is already not in the foreground. moveTaskToBack(true) doesn't terminate the application either, that's done by calling finish() on your activity, which would trigger the system to destroy your application process.

Comment: But I am using the moveTaskToBack(true) to get the app off the screen, is there another way to do that, and why would that invoke onStop anyways?

Comment: Okay, so I added this.finish to my onPause, and then added super.onStop to my onStop, and still no go, but this time it does a full force close, it doesn't just flash the box, I am confused as to why it would flash like that

Comment: It also says fatal exception if that means anything

Comment: Post where you're using moveTaskToBack(). You're probably using it when you don't need to.

Comment: just posted it, it doesn't do this force close anymore, but it force closes because of an outOfMemoryException, could this be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using the Activity.finish() function to close your app?